# DITA OT 2.2.1 upgrade problems

Tags: dita-ot

I'm upgrading from version 1.2.2 of DITA-OT to 2.2.1, and I'm having a couple of issues regarding PDF output with fop:

1 - The TOC keeps printing the page numbers in roman numerals, instead of arabic.
Where can I change the output format?

2 - When trying to set a PDF background image for a fo:block-container or a fo:table, the output is the following:

```
[fop] [ERROR] Image not available. 
URI: Customization/OpenTopic/common/artwork/cover.pdf.
Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. 
No ImagePreloader found for Customization/OpenTopic/common/artwork/cover.pdf (See position 1:-1)
```

For example, the block-container definition is the following:

```
<fo:block-container absolute-position="fixed" left="12mm" top="0mm" background-repeat="no-repeat">
  <xsl:attribute name="background-image">
    <xsl:value-of select="&quot;url(&apos;Customization/OpenTopic/common/artwork/cover&quot;"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$cover"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="&quot;.pdf&apos;)&quot;"/>
  </xsl:attribute>-->
<fo:block/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things have changed, since 1.2.2. If possible, generate a a new PDF-plugin using the [dita-generator](http://dita-generator-hrd.appspot.com/), this is probably faster than trying to fix your old plugin.

1. Generate a new plugin.
2. Publish your content with the new plugin.
3. If it succeeds, copy a single template from the old plugin to the new plugin and test again.
4. Repeat 3. until you're done.

Comment: Will give it a go :)
Although, does this also solve my image PDF issue?

Comment: You are trying to use a PDF as an image container. This is not a supported format, according to the [Apache FOP docs](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/graphics.html). Maybe Antenna House (or whatever you use) supports this, I don't know. You should try another file format, e.g. PNG for pixel graphics and SVG for vector graphics.

Comment: Thanks! I've switched to XEP instead, and XEP supports PDF images as PDF covers.

Comment: Hmm... I looked again at your error message. The `[FOP]` indicates, that Apache FOP is used here. You need to set the `pdf.formatter` parameter, see [PDF parameters](http://www.dita-ot.org/dev/parameters/parameters-pdf.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is an Apache FOP plugin which adds support for using PDF images:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fop-pdf-images.html